# geniso with hfsbless not working

Tags: linux, macos, bash

I created a top level folder "top" and a sub level folder "sub" and would like to bless folder "sub" with genisoimage.

genisoimage -r -J -V "top"  --hfs-bless top/sub -o top.iso top.

Apparently my folder "sub" is not blessed when i insert the top.iso image in MAC.

Am i missing anything here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes -- you haven't specified the `--hfs` flag, so your ISO image doesn't contain a HFS filesystem, and thus can't have a blessed folder.

That being said: Blessed folders mostly stopped being a thing when Mac OS X came out. Unless you're trying to build some sort of weird multi-OS boot CD, I'm not sure this is something you want.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to create an hybrid ISO image in linux as my final target is based on linux. I tried your option as "genisoimage -r -J -V "top" --hfs --hfs-bless top/sub -o top.iso top" and still the "top" folder pops up instead "sub" folder..  I also see this warning "genisoimage: Warning: no Apple/Unix files will be decoded/mapped" .. Is this warning creating problem?.

Comment: Blessing a folder doesn't make it show up when the disk is inserted! It just specifies that the directory should contain files to be used when booting the machine. Unless your CD can be used as a boot disk for a Mac, do not use `--hfs-bless`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the issue. I was confused the way "bless" command in MAC works.. Is there any way to make the folder "sub" show up when the disk is inserted with "genisoimage" OR with any other utility?.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible -- at the very least, I've never seen a CD that behaved that way. I'd recommend that you instead try using a complication of `--hide-hfs` and `--hide-joliet` to present a different set of files on the disk to OS X users and everyone else.

Comment: Did I hit an dead end? May be i should start looking how bless with --open-folder and without --open-folder works(by looking at the few initial sectors and pretend them with "dd" command). I also need the hiding options along with showing up an folder when the ISO image is inserted for better user experience.